# Software to help me create an approximate route (just sites and arrows) on a map?

Tags: software-recommendation, maps, technical-drawing

I'm in the middle of writing a thesis on the most authentic Exodus route (following the clues given in the bible). I would like to demonstrate on a map the sites and locations where the Israelites stayed (during the forty year wandering) as well as the route they took to get to Canaan. I tried creating one with Google maps but the problem with maps is that it gives me an exact route which is unsuitable for my needs, given that these ancient routes are at best uncertain, and I feel that giving an exact route is misleading to readers. Furthermore, most of the highways that Google follows most probably did not exist 3000 years ago! Sometimes it will give me an unnecessary long and complicated route from point A to B because no direct roads exist nowadays between the two. I was looking for a program that would give me the ability to create an approximate route, e.g., arrows to show where they went, but is not too exact. Check [this link](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/642959284274729439/?nic_v2=1aPGCv844) to see the kind of route I have in mind. Arrows are necessary in battle maps to show the many positions generals take (marching, retreating, redeploying), and various formations, so I'm quite confident that software like these exist.

Comment: Practically *any* image editing or layout application will allow this - some better at some aspects than others. Have you looked into anything? i.e. This is rather broad if you haven't done any research and narrowed possibilities at least some.

Comment: @Scott so far I have only tried maps related software which turned out to be unsuitable for me. I have no experience with image editing software, so I can't say that I did. In any case, image editing alone would not be sufficient since I would have to first plot out the location on a real map, only then can I add text and arrows and routes, etc., unless of course I create points on a map, then upload to some other software and add the above, which sounds overly complicated. Your thoughts?

Comment: So, are you seeking more cartography software? That may not be in the purview of most users here. With most image editing software, you can open any image and draw/type on top of it. Chances are whatever computer system you are using has some default image editor installed which can do that. However, if you need long/lat coordinates input, that's cartography far more than graphic design. -- Realize I could be wrong entirely.  This is merely my opinion.

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure why you think this is cartography related, I see it more as a design software question. Any maps related software would have been perfect if it had couple of extra tools to play around with. In any case I appreciate your help!

Comment: I see it as cartography because you "need to plot the location". Graphic software won't do that.

Comment: Find a suitable map- an "area" map rather than a street map- then import it as a (.pdf, a .png, a .jpg or whatever format) into a "simple" drawing program to plot your routes, do your arrows, signage, etc. A vector drawing program like Inkscape or Illustrator would certainly do it, but it will have a pretty steep learning curve for you. I have a simple app on my mac called Shapes (no affiliation on my part) that would work for what you are wanting. A search will probably net you many choices. If you have to create your entire map then that is a different story.

Comment: @Kyle thanks for your help. The real question is, where do I source my bible maps. Most maps would not include all my biblical sites, and those that do don't show the topography that I want, or they include a route which I don't need or want. It's almost impossible to find a map that's suitable for me. I tried creating my locations in maps and to import that map unto inkscape, but that too is not very suitable. I need something more specifically designed for this.

Comment: If you cannot find a suitable "base map" then you can make one in pretty much any vector drawing program. You mention Inkscape and that is a very capable (and free) vector drawing program.